# which framework, CMS etc. for a webpage

Tags: php, magento, frameworks, content-management-system, yii

I'm about to start a new project. It's about selling one completely customizable product.
therefore its core elements will be

- Static pages
- an extensive configurator with heavy jQuery+AJAX UI
- registration, basket, checkout
- Payment gateway integration (paypal etc)
- backend: billing, order management
- Email notifications
- Social Media integration - Twitter feed etc
- User sign up / subscription

i'm torn between using OXID/Magento or starting from scratch with a php framework as yii.
but i am open to any other better solutions.
The advantages of OXID/Magento is that it already covers the whole "shop" part, but would need changes how to integrate a complete customized product with an configurator, it seems also a bit too much for just one product and heavy loaded to use a full blown shopping cms.
With a framework like yii i would have to write lots of its functionality (checkout,billing,backend etc) from scratch but would have a cleaner solution and maybe less headaches and problems programming modules or customizing OXID/Magento at its core.

My background is PHP!

Any advice would be great,

thanks a lot,

Christoph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your project requirements, how much time/money you have if:

1. Your time to market is short (less than one month), and you need to a have a fast presence in the market. Your business requirements have simple 1-1 mapping with CMS features, then go with a CMS such as Magento/Joomla/Drupal, etc.. depending of how much features each one achieve for you. Here a discussion about simpler Magento alternatives " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693169/a-good-ecommerce-alternative-to-magento " OR you can check [wordpress e-commerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/).
2. If you care about performance, scalability,high customization,moderate business requirements, you have time (3-6 months). Then for sure go and build your own solution using some PHP framework Yii/Zend,etc.
3. If you are writing a mission-critical system for the long run. That need to handle millions of users, you have time (more than 6 months). Then you will need to write everything from scratch, write your own PHP extensions, leverage cloud storage, etc..

Comment: thanks for the fast and detailed answer!
the thing about mangento is, that it seems bit too much for just one product. as you leave big parts of the shopsystem aside. "just" configuration, checkout and done has to be done in the frontend. 
I got no big experience with joomla, drupal or django. i suppose it would need heavy integrations of "shopping"-extensions to make it work right?
yeah time to market is crucial (end of the year)

Comment: Yes you are right, Magento is complex for small business. In this I would recommend using other open-source CMS with plugin for example:
Wordpress e-Commerce plugin, wordpress is relatively simpler system
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/

Here also you will find SO discussion about Magento alternavies
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693169/a-good-ecommerce-alternative-to-magento

Comment: wp e-commerce seems. i'll have a look and make a demo installation thanks a lot so far! maybe i'll be back ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I recall well, both OXID and Magento are coded using Zend. So I'd say that your initial idea to combine them is a good one because it means you could extend the initial app with your own classes, sticking within Zend.

The drawback is that Zend's native Javascript framework, that apparently also comes with Magento, is Dojo, which I've heard isn't nearly as developer-friendly as JQuery.

So perhaps you should add the Magento jQuery Base extention (http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/javascript_related/how_to_use_jquery_1.2.6_lastest_with_prototype)

This way you'll be zend all the way (that pun was lame) but you'd rely on JQuery for the heavy Ajax and UI job you're mentioning.

Comment: yeah i prefer oxid over magento, because its less complex!
Just not completely sure how to integrate one completely custom product and how to save that back to the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of that with Magento. Most of it is in core, some of it you can write custom modules for.

Answer (score 0):

As CMS I like Joomla because of it's flexibility (certainly since version 1.7). For a blog: WordPress and as framework you can also use Joomla or two other options I've tried and liked are: CodeIgniter and Yii.

MAgento is also a good option with great possibilities but it's a bit hard to get into it. Also it is a bit slow so you need a decent server to host a magento website..